# SQL Server varbinary(max) to Oracle LONG RAW

Tags: sql-server, oracle, integration

I am trying to push binary data from SQL Server to an Oracle LONG RAW column.  I have a linked server created on SQL Server that connects to the Oracle server.  I have a stored procedure on the Oracle side that I am trying to call from SQL Server.  I can't seem to get the binary to pass into the stored procedure.  I've tried changing the from and to types; however, the data ultimately needs to end up in a LONG RAW column.  I have control of the Oracle stored procedure and the SQL Server code, but I do not have control of the predefined Oracle table structure.

**varbinary(max) -> long raw**
    *ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested*

**varbinary(max) -> blob**
    *PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'ADDDOC'*

**varbinary -> long raw**
    *No errors, but get data truncation or corruption*

The varbinary(max) does work if I set the @doc = null.

Below is the Oracle procedure and the SQL Server.

Oracle:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE ADDDOC (param1 IN LONG RAW)
AS
BEGIN
  -- insert param1 into a LONG RAW column
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TEST');
END ADDDOC;
```

SQL Server:

```
declare @doc varbinary(max)
select top 1 @doc = Document from Attachments

execute ('begin ADDDOC(?); end;', @doc) at ORACLE_DEV

-- tried this too, same error
--execute ('begin ADDDOC(utl_raw.cast_to_raw(?)); end;', @doc) at ORACLE_DEV
```

I've also tried creating the record in the Oracle Documents table then updating the LONG RAW field from SQL Server without invoking a stored procedure, but the query just seems to run and run and run and run...

```
--already created record and got the Id of the record I want to put the data in
--hard coding for this example
declare @attachmentId, @documentId
set @attachmentId = 1
set @documentId = 1

update ORACLE_DEV..MYDB.Documents
set Document = (select Document from Attachments where Id = @attachmentId)
where DocumentId=@documentId
```

Comment: `LONG` and `LONG RAW` have been depricated since the Oracle 8.0 days ~20 years ago.  They were depricated because they were a *royal* pain to support and relatively few APIs are capable of dealing with them robustly.  Maybe someone will be able to come along and suggest a way to get a linked server connection to support a `LONG RAW` but I wouldn't be shocked if you had to use a different approach.

Comment: Do **not** use `LONG` or `LONG RAW`. The *only* sensible match for SQL Server's `varbinary` is `BLOB`.

Comment: I am seeing that LONG RAW is a royal pain.  The Oracle table structure is the backend of a third party product that I need to integrate with so changing the datatype is out of my hands.  I've tried changing the stored procedure parameter to BLOB, but get the "wrong number or types of arguments" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, LONG RAW is very difficult to work with; unfortunately, our vendor is using the datatype in their product and I have no choice but to work with it.  I found that I could not pass binary data from SQL Server to an Oracle stored procedure parameter.  I ended up having to create a new record with a NULL value for the LONG RAW field then using an OPENQUERY update to set the field to the VARBINARY(MAX) field; I did try using an update with the four part identifier, as noted in my code sample, but it took over 11 minutes for a single update, this new approach completes in less than 3 seconds.  I am using an Oracle stored procedure here because in my real world scenario I am creating multiple records in multiple tables and coded business logic that is not relevant then tying them together with the docId.

This feels more like a workaround than a solution, but it actually works with acceptable performance.

Oracle:

```
create or replace procedure ADDDOC(docId OUT Number)
as
begin
    select docseq.nextval into docId from dual;

    -- insert new row, but leave Document LONG RAW field null for now
    insert into DOC (Id) values(docId);
end ADDDOC;
```

SQL Server:

```
declare @DocId float, @AttachmentID int, @Qry nvarchar(max)
set @AttachmentID = 123 -- hardcoded for example

execute('begin ADDDOC(?); end;', @DocId output) at ORACLE_DEV

-- write openquery sql that will update Oracle LONG RAW field from a SQL Server varbinary(max) field
set @Qry = '
    update openquery(ORACLE_DEV, ''select Document from Documents where Id=' + cast(@DocId as varchar) + ''')
    set Document = (select Document from Attachments where Id = ' + cast(@AttachmentID as varchar) + ')
    '
execute sp_executesql @Qry
```